# Windows is in BIOS mode and dual-boot it with Ubuntu in UEFI mode

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, uefi, boot-partition

I have Windows 7 and I want to dual boot it with Ubuntu 16.04.2. But when I am installing from Bootable USB, it shows a message as follows

> This machine's firmware has started the installer in UEFI mode but it looks like there may be some existing operating systems already using "BIOS compatibility mode". If you continue to install Debian in UEFI mode, it might be difficult to reboot the machine into any BIOS-mode operating systems later.
>
> If you wish to install in UEFI mode and don't care about keeping the ability to boot one of the operating systems, you have the option to force that here. If you wish to keep the option to boot an existing operating system, you should choose NOT to force UEFI installation here.

[image]

**I tried**

- to change from BIOS to UEFI in Boot Option but after changing no
  drive is showing from which system can boot.
- to make the USB bootable from [Rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) and [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io/), but in both cases it shows same problem message.

**Question**

1. I am getting both /boot and /EFI folder even when my chose partition
   scheme is **MBR partition scheme for BIOS/UEFI**. So as some online material suggested choosing the required partition scheme will resolve the problem, my question is how can it be solved if always a /EFI getting
   generated??
2. Is this a problem of hardware OR OS conflict(i.e one OS is on BIOS and the other one is on UEFI)? In either case what can be done?
3. Can this be a problem due to ISO image which I am using? Can this be
           resolved if I use another ISO image?(If yes then how I can know
           which ISO image I should choose?)

Comment: I believe it's best if both operating systems are installed in the same mode:  if Windows (already installed) is using BIOS, then you should install Ubuntu in BIOS mode.

Comment: So What should be the partition scheme in Rufus?? @CharlesGreen

Comment: With newer UEFI hardware, it is how you boot install media UEFI or BIOS boot is then how it installs. So you should have two boot options from UEFI boot menu for flash drive. One clearly UEFI and other just name of label of flash drive which would be a BIOS boot. But BIOS/MBR is 35 year old, so not the optimum choice, but usable. And all operating system should be in same boot mode. And Windows determines whether MBR or gpt as it only can boot in BIOS mode from MBR and only in UEFI mode from gpt.

Comment: Yes. But the  choices are UEFI or UEFI/BIOS, and I have tried with both.